# What's the difference between "walk someone over to" and "walk over to"

Tags: grammar, idioms, phrasal-verbs

I heard that "walk someone over to" means accompany someone to a destination, but I am wondering "walk over to" means something, I want to say "walk a short distance to go talk to someone", but I am not sure if "walk over to" can be used without a direct object (someone).

For example:

> He walked over to Mark who was near the tree signaling to hurry up,
>   and had a little chat with him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you understand the difference in meaning.  "Walk over to" is a simple action where the subject moves to a location at a walking pace:

> I spotted Mary across the crowded room and **walked over to** her.  "Some party, huh?" I asked, with all the casual cool I could summon.

"Walk *someone* over to" is a different action where you *guide* someone to some location at a walking pace.

> The student looked lost, so I **walked him over to** the administration building where he could register for classes.

Depending on the context, "walk someone over to" can also imply coercion, or threat of force.

> The guards lined up the prisoners and **walked them over** to the gates of the dentention camp, watching them carefully the entire way.

Comment: I asked, because I don't see walk over to in the dictionary. I just see two entries for walk over, but nothing else. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/walk